# Quadritaisho: An introduction

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction

<sub>TL;DR: Nikoli's [Tentai Show](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/tentai_show/), but with four different types of symmetry.</sub>

Rules of Quadritaisho:

- Divide the grid into rooms by drawing borders along grid lines.
- Each room contains exactly one symbol (circle, diamond, vertical bar, or horizontal bar).
- Rooms with a vertical bar **|** are symmetrical along an axis which runs vertically through the bar.
- Rooms with a horizontal bar **—** are symmetrical along an axis which runs horizontally through the bar.
- Rooms with a circle ● are 180° rotationally symmetrical, with the circle in the central point.
- Rooms with a diamond ◆ are 90° rotationally symmetrical, with the diamond in the central point.

An example of a valid room with each symbol:

[image: Example image displaying the use of each symbol]

The puzzle:
[image: Empty Quadritaisho grid]
[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/yu98vytf)

Comment: Testing out this format. Original idea by @oAlt in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64410197#64410197).

Comment: Nevermind. Whilst trying solving this in mind, I found that the presence of a symbol doesn't prohibit other symmetries.

Comment: @DannyuNDos Yeah so just to clarify, a room is allowed to have other symmetries as long as it has *at least* the specific type indicated by its symbol. So for example a 1x1 room would be valid with any of the four possible symbols.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complete grid:

> [image]

Step by step solution:

> Start with some basic deductions to draw some edges:
>
> Each area must contain a single symbol (black edges).
>
> Symmetry rules for those edges, and the grid border (green edges)
>  [image]

> Now, lets look at cells that can only be reached from a single symbol.
>
> Three cells top-right that must be with the vertical bar below.
>
> Two cells to the left of those that must be with the top-centre diamond.
>
> Two cells at the bottom that must be with the vertical bar bottom-centre.
>  [image]
>
>  Applying symmetry rules to those cells (and ensuring those in the top right reach to the vertical bar) gets us to:
>  [image]
>
>  Now the marked cell bottom-right must be part of the diamond, and the symmetry rules fully define that region (green).
>  That defines bottom-centre region (blue).
>  We can also complete the horizontal-bar region at the top (blue).
>  And add a couple more edges (red) from symmetry rules.
>  [image]

> Now the marked cell in R5C2 can only be part of the remaining horizontal-bar region.
>  So all the green cells must part of that region. And applying the symmetry rules to the known edges completes that region.
>  And finally applying symmetry rules to the circle regions (starting with the upper one) completes the grid (blue).
>  [image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution. I'm pretty sure the solution is unique:

> [image]

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind your solution path so that a reader could understand *how* to solve this puzzle, please? That would make this answer much more useful... Thanks!